# how i can add token to http get request to rest api

Tags: angular, token

```
export class ProfileService {
    public apiUrl:string='http://xyz/api';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private reqHeaders:HttpHeaders) {}

    public getProfile(): Observable<any>
    { 

        var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({
           'Content-Type':'application/json',
           'Authorization':JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'))
        })
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/info.json',{reqHeaders}).map(
            (data)=>console.log(data)

        )
    }
```

Comment: Care to elaborate more on the issue like specifying what issues you are facing or what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of naming your object `reqHeaders` just name it `headers`, it should work fine then. Take a look at `get` definition:

```
get<T>(url: string, options?: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<T>;
```

You can also utilize HttpInterceptors to add authentication to your requests ([more#1](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses), [more#2](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)).

By the way, you don't have to set Content-Type to `application/json`, because it's the default one.

By the way #2, your title is wrong, because you are asking about Angular, not AngularJS.